# Plot certain parts of column of a matrix

Tags: plotting, matrix

I have a text file `data1` (not comma separated) that consists of a huge number of numbers, it's basically a matrix of numbers. I would like to have a smooth code to e.g. plot columns $a$ to $b$ but only between rows $c$ and $d$. The following ugly ass code works for the special case of plotting the full columns

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{data1[[All, {1, 3}]], data1[[All, {1, 4}]], 
  data1[[All, {1, 5}]], data1[[All, {1, 6}]], data1[[All, {1, 7}]], 
  data1[[All, {1, 8}]], data1[[All, {1, 9}]], data1[[All, {1, 10}]]},
```

As can be seen I have put in manually instead of a nice code. Also I suspect one could change `All` to something that only takes row $c$ to $d$. Is this possible and if so what is a nice code for that?

Comment: Have you looked into the syntax `data[[a;;b,c;;d]]`, et c.? This lets you pull parts `a` through `b` of the top level, `c` through `d` of the second level, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Generate some matrix:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]
```

Then, to take e.g. rows from 2 to 4, and columns from 7 to 9, use `Span`:

```
subdata = data[[2 ;; 4, 7 ;; 9]]
```

> {{0.29785, 0.186604, 0.0372086}, {0.222346, 0.578416, 
>     0.1889}, {0.346148, 0.731862, 0.889276}}

```
ListLogLinearPlot[subdata, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]